# Can't access POST Variables sent from angular 4 in slim php

Tags: json, angular, slim

I'm trying to build a little Angular 4 Application with a rest api build with slim php. I'm having touble to access the POST variables on specific routes, while it works perfectly on at least one route. Here is my code:

```
// Log In A League { "email": $email, "pass": $pass }
$app->post('/api/users/league-login', function(Request $request, Response $response){
  require "user_management/league_login.php";
  $logIn = new LeagueLogIn();
  $logIn->logIn($request->getParam("email"), $request->getParam("pass"));
});
```

Angular sends this JSON:

```
Object { email: “test@test.com", pass: "000" }
```

This works perfectly. But on this rout I can't access the POST variables with $request->getParam()

```
// Add Team To A League { "name": $name, "email": $email }
$app->post('/api/league/team', function(Request $request, Response $response){
  require "user_management/team_create.php";
  $user = authorizeToken($request->getHeader('Authorization'));
  $teamCreate = new TeamCreate();
  $teamCreate->create($request->getParam("name"), $request->getParam("email"), $user);
});
```

Angular sends this JSON

```
Object { name: "name", email: "test2@test.com" }
```

As soon as I add double quotes on the keys manually for the request:

```
Object { "name": "name", "email": "test2@test.com" }
```

it works perfectly.

Does somebody know what kind of problem this is, or what I'm overlooking?

Comment: its because the json object created in angular doesnt format the quotes as it doesnt require them, when it gets send via a http request, it should add the quotes in

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand why it works on the log in but not on the add team.

Comment: Got it, I was echoing strings during the process so the response from the server wasn't a valid json.